# Fresh Ubuntu Install Rtl88x2bu wireless adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I'm having a really difficult time getting this wifi usb adapter working on a fresh install. Last night I hopped from Manjaro where it was working (with some config originally) to Ubuntu. The Adapter is a Realtek **8812BU** Wireless USB. I have gone through each of the other postings with a similar issue but none seemed to solve my issue. I'm guessing it is the last step of below that never completes.

Here is what i've tried. I saw on some other posts that this git repo https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu was useful in getting it to work. So I did the following.

```
Clone the repo
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

However on the very last step (modprobe) my terminal just hangs there every time. I've even given it over an hour on one try.

Running:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: You said that your adapter is **Realtek 8812BU**, but it looks like you're trying to install drivers for **RTL88X2BU**. Are you sure this is the correct driver? Installing incorrect drivers and/or firmware can brick a device so I hope you're not wrong here.

Comment: I thought they were the same? RTL is the abbreviation for Realtek and the X is because 8812BU and 8822BU use the same driver? I could be wrong here

Comment: another fact: if I type less /proc/modules, 88x2BU is on loading and not live

Comment: So I was able to solve it by following this resource: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2448169&page=2 it seems that the issue was module 8822 was loaded on the kernel but tainting it. After removing it everything works perfectly. I'll leave the answer for if anyone knows why this occurred

Comment: Alright let me dig in a bit tonight and draft out an answer, then i'll post it

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments, I was able to solve my issue after noticing that kernel module 8822 was loading but never live. After a big of digging through logs I saw that I was getting an out-of-tree module taints kernel message. I removed the module with the following code:

```
sudo dkms remove 8822bu/1.1 --all
```

Then after a reboot everything was working perfectly.